# JavaScript not functioning within Update Panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net

why java script not work within update panel,  i need add update panel to content place holder in site master in asp.net web form..but all Java script stops functioning in all other pages, is there any solution for this?

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updater" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
          </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: How are you calling the javascript function?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your page, it should solve

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="section2" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Sys.Application.add_load(JavascriptFunctionName);
    </script>
   </asp:Content>
```

Note : if you are calling the same function on page load you can remove